# Expressing schedule of reinforcement rule using mathematical logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I am trying to formalize the rules for application of different schedules in a reinforcement learning in special education. Children learn through trials. Each trial is successful if the child exhibits the correct behavior. Correct behavior is reinforced according to different schedules of reinforcement:

**Continuous**, (reinforce every correct answer),
**Fixed Ratio** (every n-th correct answer),
**Variable Ratio** (every, *on average*, n-th correct answer),
**Fixed Interval** (reinforce every n-th minute), and
**Variable Interval** (every n-th minute *on average*).

Here is what I have so far, and I would like to ask here if you can take a look and tell me if I've done it right. There is a separate challenge how to select what to average is, but for now I would like to ask you to take a look at my formulae and tell me if there is something to be fixed and how.

**Continuous Reinforcement** $CR$:

*Formula*: Let $s$ be a student under instruction, $R$ be a student's behavioral response, and $r$ be a suitable reinforcer.
We define Continuous Reinforcement schedule as:

$CR := \forall R$ Correct$(R) \to$ Reinforce$(s,r)$

**Fixed Ratio** $FR_n$

*Formula:* Let $s$ be a student under instruction, $n$ be a ratio of reinforcement (every n-th), $i_{lr}$ index of the trial when the behavior was last reinforced, $i_c$ index of the current trial, $R$ be a student's behavioral response, and $r$ be a suitable reinforcer.

We define Fixed Ratio schedule as:

$FR_n := ((\forall R,$ Correct$(R) \land ((i_c - i_{lr})=n)) \to$ Reinforce$(s,r))$

**Fixed Interval** $FI_t$

Let $s$ be a student under instruction,
$R$ be a student's behavioral response,
$t_l$ be the time since the last reinforcement, $t_c$ be the current time, $t$ be the interval of reinforcement, and $r$ be a suitable reinforcer.

We define Fixed Interval schedule as:

$FI_t := ((\forall R,$ Correct$(R) \land (t_c-t_l)\geq t) \to$(Reinforce$(s,r)) \land t_l = t_c $)